# ember build fails after code change

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I am trying to run ember locally on my Windows 7 machine

When I load my app for the first time, the ember build is successful and ember serve starts and I can access my app.

However, as soon as I make even a small change in my code and try to refresh, I get the following error;

> ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty
>   'C:\MyCode\myProj\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-cQOjj10S.tmp\modules\ember-validations\validators'

I am using Sublime Text editor and have added the following in Preferences: Settings > User

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS", "tmp/*"]
```

While I have seen other solutions like 
Disable Windows Search Index for temporary files (Windows does not seem to be already indexing my tmp folder)
Disable Windows Defender for temporary files

Please note I do not have Admin rights on my system (it's a company provided system).
I do have anti-virus running, but cannot disable it.
So kindly suggest any fixes accordingly.

Comment: Who is the owner of your `myProj` and `myProj\tmp` directories?

Comment: it is on my local Windows 7 machine and created by me itself (i.e. same user who has created the folder is running the ember serve command)...But I the user does not have admin access